# How can I be sure that my internet service provider is safe?

Tags: wifi, account-security, internet

There is a new internet service provider in town that provides fiber internet--their internet is fast and it's proven. Almost everyone in our town switched to their internet. However, I am kind of skeptical to subscribe for some reasons:

1. They don't have a website, just a facebook page with 500 likes :< Their business name is also suspicious as they're only called "Fiber Speed" which is a very common name and doesn't even sound as a business name.
2. They only operate in small towns, not even more than 10 towns.
3. They said they get their internet from a popular network in our country and I can confirm that since I saw it in the speedtest but they offer their fiber internet for a cheaper price, I'm not even sure if they operate legally lol.
4. I don't think they have an office. They also have these flyers that are obviously not professionally designed.

I am just worried about my internet security because I do a lot of online bank transactions as I work as a freelancer online. I always use VPN when connected to their network because I don't feel safe.

How can I make sure their internet is safe and they're not trying to spy on the information we share online?

Comment: All of these seem pretty reasonable for a very small company of any type - including an ISP. Considering that the big ISPs mostly exist to fleece you out of your money, an ISP being small isn't a red flag and can even be a green flag.

Comment: (also note that all the big ISPs are wiretapped by the NSA at all times; Comcast or Verizon or AT&T isn't necessarily as safe as you think)

Comment: online banking uses https, no need to worry.

Answer (score 3):

While I certainly wouldn't recommend using an ISP that seems dubious, there's no need to fully trust an ISP either.

The de-facto standard for any serious online application is to use end-to-end encryption, e. g. through HTTPS. If properly implemented, this reliably prevents the ISP or any other intermediary from reading or manipulating the traffic. The Internet generally shouldn't be considered trustworthy, regardless of the ISP you're using.

Note that DNS traffic (i. e. the domains you're visiting) is usually neither encrypted nor authenticated. If you want to protect this data as well, you need to use a [DNS resolver which supports encryption](https://dnsprivacy.org/public_resolvers/).

So both the traffic and DNS lookups can and should be protected in any case. The remaining issue is that metadata -- the IP addresses you communicate with, the time when this happens and the amount of data -- *will* be visible to your ISP. If that's a problem, there's [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). I'm not sure if I'd consider VPN a solution. As Steffen Ullrich already said, you're just shifting trust from one entity to another, and VPNs aren't necessarily more trustworthy than ISPs.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make sure their internet is safe and they're not trying to spy on the information we share online?

There is no way to ensure that your internet provider is "safe" - whatever this exactly means. Since you have no way to verify the providers infrastructure and to asses the corporation including all its employees, it basically boils down to deriving your trust from the few information you find. This is what you are already doing and it is unlikely you can do more.

There are a few options you can take:

- Don't use the new internet provider, but continue what you've used so far in the hope that it was better. Note that you unlikely have more reliable information about your current provider than you have about the new one - only that the current one has built a better reputation over time and probably has an interest in maintaining this valuable reputation.
- Use the new internet provider in the hope that there are regulations which  address the concerns you have, i.e. privacy laws etc. How much of these regulations exist and how much protection they actually offer depends on where you live.
- Use the new internet provider but trust it only for availability. This means using the provider just to get the connectivity to some VPN endpoint. Of course, this basically moves the trust from the ISP to whoever maintains the infrastructure of the VPN endpoint.

But, if the company is not meeting your expectations on basic professional appearance (no website, shoddy flyers) then you might not even trust the provider for availability alone. If you depend on availability (i.e. no backup) then you might better stick with what you currently have for now and reevaluate the situation later.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "trustworthy" or "insecure" ISP.

1. When you're connecting to your ISP, you're connected using wires or Wi-Fi both of which can be compromised one way or another. For instance Wi-Fi routers are often hacked because they are not updated automatically or no new firmware is getting released. Many wired routers are not properly configured, e.g. can be accessed using default (simple or leaked) passwords, some routers have "forgotten" vendor backdoors, etc.
2. Your ISP does not connect to endpoint websites right away, there are numerous other Internet providers/switches/companies in between. Any of them can be compromised.

The net result is the following: when you're connecting to any network you should treat it as compromised. No ifs. If the network is compromised that means:

- Your OS must be fully updated and secure
- Your network ports must be properly firewalled
- Your software must be up to date and secure (web browsers, any servers, etc.)
- You must be using DoT or DoH. Your resolver should be able to use DNSSEC as well.
- You must be using HTTPS for websites where security and privacy are essential (banking/finances/social networks/etc.)

Comment: You should consider your ISP as _untrusted_, but an ISP can still be more insecure than other (mainly due to things out of your control or even unknown, such as the policies they enforce, the warrants they might receive...). That if they are really interested they might be able to gather your data anyway does not require you to contract your service with "NSA spies LLC",